# Upload data to Spinner and DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, tableview, spinner

I have this code so that when I select a record in the TableView they load me automatically in their respective fields:

```
 public void gestionarEvento() {
tblViewProductos.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<Productos>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Productos> observable, Productos valorAnterior, Productos valorSeleccionado) {
        if (valorSeleccionado != null) {
            txtidProducto.setText(String.valueOf(valorSeleccionado.getIdPro()));
            txtdescripcionPro.setText(valorSeleccionado.getDescripcion());
            spnMax.setValueFactory(Integer.parseInt(Integer.valueOf(valorSeleccionado.getStockMax())));//ERROR

            btnEliminar.setDisable(false);
            btnActualizar.setDisable(false);
        }
    }

});
tblViewPrecio.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Precio>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Precio> observable, Precio valorAnterior, Precio valorSeleccionado) {
        if (valorSeleccionado != null) {
            txtidPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(valorSeleccionado.getIdPre()));
            txtfechaInicio.setValue(Date.valueOf(valorSeleccionado.getFechaInicio()));//ERROR

        }
    }
});
```

}

I have tried many things but I still can not load that data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Qgt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spnMax.setValueFactory takes a factory as an input argument, but you are trying to provide an integer.

Instead try

```
SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(minValue, maxValue, yourValue);
```

For the DatePicker, try using java.time.LocalDate class

Comment: the datepicker solve it as follows "txtfechaInicio.setValue(valorSeleccionado.getFechaInicio().toLocalDate());"              now with the spinner, your help helped me a little, SpinnerValueFactory <Integer> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory (*, *, *);
spnMax.setValueFactory (valueFactory);

but I want you to load the Selected Value in said spinner, it could be like this:
SpinnerValueFactory <Integer> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory (valueSelected.getStockMax (), 0, 12); ?
is what I can think of

Comment: Hello again, you can solve it in the following way
SpinnerValueFactory <Integer> valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory (0, valueSelected.getStockMax (), valueSelected.getStockMax ());

spnMax.setValueFactory (valueFactory);

Thanks for your help.